# How to align two Bootstrap columns below each other?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I struggle with the alignment of Bootstrap columns at the moment.
Could you help me please?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p style="background-color: #C3C3C3">
                DIV 1 - content should be on the left.<br />
                This content is higher then the right (DIV 2) content.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p style="background-color: #D1D1D1">
                DIV 2 - content should be on the right.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p style="background-color: #F1F1F1">
                DIV 3 - Content should be on the desktop right. And
                mobile below both DIVs.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result should look like this:

[Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIw45.png)
[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz4w2.png)

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/16tmg7hz/8/

Answer (score 2):

You've created a row that has 20 columns (4 + 8 + 8). Boostrap is based on a 12 column model.

To align the third column below columns 1 and 2, you need to create a new row, `<div class="row"></div>`.

If you want content in div1 to be above div2, that's a little difficult in your current code. div1, div2, and div3 are all flush to the top of the row you've created. You could consider adding the styling `margin-top` to div2.